# JQuery Not equal to selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I do something if only the selector's attr is not equal to a certain value?

For example:

```
  function date_box(thisdiv){
  var week = $(thisdiv).attr("week");
   $(".gospel_table5[week!="+week+"]").hide();
}
```

To put into human, if the `attr week` is not equal to the `week variable`, then hide the `gospel_table5` behind this information. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Should work perfectly. See https://jsfiddle.net/43oLzhjq/.
Perhaps something else is wrong with the selector?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `:not()` pseudo-class (or whatever they're called):

```
$(".gospel_table5:not([week=" + week + "])").hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `:not(selector)`. replace `selector` with what you want to negate.